# Solving the Sturm-Liouville problem using Green's function and Spectral Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, differential-operators, sturm-liouville

I am reading a paper that deals with the solution of the Sturm-Liouville problem:

> $u''(t) + \rho (t) u + \lambda ^{-1}u= -f $
>
> $ u(0)=u(1)=0$

For $\rho(t) \leq 0 $.
First it is solved the problem:

> $u''(t) + \rho (t) u= -f $
>
> $u(0)=u(1)=0 \hspace{1cm}$  **(1)**

Picking two arbitrary linearly independent solutions $u_1,u_2, u_1(0)=0$ $u_2(1)=0$ and using Variation of constants method to obtain a particular solution $u_p$. Then, by imposing to the general solution $u=u_p +a u_1 +b u_2$ the boundary conditions of the original **(1)** problem, it is found the solution that the solution to **(1)**  is written in integral form as $ \int_{0}^{1} k(t,s)f(s)ds$. So it is defined the operator $K$:

$$K:L^2([0,1]) \hspace{1cm} \longrightarrow \hspace{1cm} L^2([0,1])$$ 
 $$ \hspace{4cm} f \hspace{1cm} \longrightarrow \hspace{1cm} u(t)= \int_{0}^{1} k(t,s)f(s)ds$$

Where u is the solution to the ODE $u'' + \rho u=f$  (With the boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$) and $k(t,s)$ is Green's Function:

$$k(t,s):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
- \frac{u_2(t)u_1(s)}{W(0)}& s \leq t \\ 
  -\frac{u_2(s)u_1(t)}{W(0)}& t\leq s
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I understand the last part of the paper which uses spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators to solve the initial problem.
But I have a few  questions:

1. It is shown that the operator $K$ is injective, so that for a given $f \in  L^2([0,1])$ there is a unique solution $u \in  L^2([0,1])$. Is this necessary? Couldn't it be shown using the fact that two different $\hat{u_1}, \hat{u_2}$ lineally independent solutions yield the same Green's function as $u_1, u_2$?
2. Also, it is shown that if  $f \in  C([0,1])$ then  $u \in  C^2([0,1])$. This is done by derivating u in its integral form two times. Again, Is this necessary? As u verifies $u'' + \rho u=f$ then $u''$ is also continuous so that $u \in  C^2([0,1])$ as long as f is continuous. Am I missing something?

Comment: But the operator is defined after the explicit solution has been found, and sends every $f \in L^2([0,1])$ to the solution $u$ of **(1)**

Comment: what do you mean with "two linearly independent solutions of (1) give the same green's function" ?

Comment: and first we solve $u'' + \rho u = 0$ not $u'' + \rho u = -f$

Comment: It is easy to show that two different $\hat{u_1}, \hat{u_2}$ lineally independent solutions yield the same Green's function as $u_1, u_2$. Also yes, of course, to solve a second order linear ode you first solve the homogeneous one. What's your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first set of equations, I think you meant
$$
         u''(t)+\rho(t)u(t) + \frac{1}{\lambda}u(t) = -f(t)
$$
instead of
$$
           u''(t)+\rho(t)u(t) + \frac{1}{\lambda} = -f(t).
$$
That's the typical way such problems are defined.

For the second set of equations
$$
\begin{array}{c}
               u''(t)+\rho(t)u(t) = -f(t),\\
               u(0)=0,\;\;\; u(1)=0,
\end{array}        \;\;\;\; (\dagger)
$$
the solution may not exist for all $f$ and may not be unique if it does exist. It depends on $\rho$. For example, suppose $\rho(t)=\pi^2$. Then $u(t)=\sin(\pi t)$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation
$$
                  u''(t)+\pi^2u(t) = 0, \\
                  u(0)=0,\;\;\; u(1)=1.
$$
Therefore if you have a solution $u_0$ of the inhomogeneous system $(\dagger)$ with $\rho(t)=\pi^2$, then $u_0+C\sin(\pi t)$ is also a solution of the inhomogenous equation for any constant $C$. So there have to be conditions on $\rho$.

Comment: $\rho(t) \leq 0$ Also yes, it is defined as you say. It was a typo.

Comment: If $\rho \le 0$, then the homogenous system has only the $0$ solution, which implies that the inhomogenous has a unique solution. That's because $u''+\rho u=0,\;u(0)=u(1)=1$, then you can assume $u$ is real, and you obtain $0=\int_{0}^{1}u''u+\rho u^2 dt = u'u|_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}u'^2dt+\int_0^1\rho u^2=\int_{0}^{1}-u'^2+\rho u^2 dt$, which implies $u=0$ because $\rho \le 0$.

Comment: Then I think I am missinterpreting something. The paper first considers the problem (Sturm-Liouville) for any $\rho \in C([0,1])$, then says it is assumed that $\rho \leq 0$ but at the step of solving **(1)**. So I wonder now Why is this problem solved at the first place...

Comment: And to my first question, it is indeed not necessary to show that $K$ is injective, Right?

Comment: @D1X : Uniqueness of solutions requires injectivity. Arguing that a particular type of construction is unique is not quite the same as saying there is only one solution. You need to say a little more if you are going to try that approach.

Comment: True... Injectivity shows different $f$'s give different solutions. And to the second question? We have built $K$ so that $K(f)$ is a solution for every $f \in L^2[(0,1)]$, so isn't it true that $f \in C([0,1])$ implies, as $K(f)'' = - \rho u -f  $, that every $u=K(f) \in C^2([0,1])$

Comment: Sorry it's $K(f)''=- \rho K(f) -f $

Comment: @D1X : That's right. There are two issues: you must show there is a solution, and you must show it is unique. Showing uniqueness is equivalent to have no non-trivial homogeneous solutions, which I've addressed above, and requires knowing something about $\rho$. Existence of a solution is given by the Green function solution, which can be verified directly. If $f \in L^2[0,1]$, then $u$ has one continuous derivative that is absolutely continuous with second derivative of $u$ equal a.e. to $f$. If you know why $f\in C[0,1]$ implies $u \in C^2[0,1]$, then you could state the reason in a solution.

Comment: I have built the solution for the ODE and put it in integral form and then defined Green's function to be the integral kernel of the solution. Doesn't automatically give me the implication $f\in C[0,1] \Rightarrow u \in C^2([0,1])$, because as  $u''=K(f)'' = - \rho u -f$ $K(f)''$ is the sum of continuous functions.

Comment: @D1X : Yes. You do need to mention that the homogeneous solutions are $C^2[0,1]$, which follows from general ODE existence/uniqueness results, provided $\rho$ is continuous.

Comment: Okay TrialAndError, thanks for your patience.

Comment: @D1X : You're welcome.